# RoR NoMethodError in Articles#new

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Showing /home/farhad/apa/blog1/app/views/articles/new.html.erb where line #13 raised:

> ```
> undefined method `phone' for #<Article:0x007fc514031070>
> ```

```
<p>
    <strong><%= f.label :phone %></strong>
    <%= f.number_field :phone %>
</p><br>
<p>
    <strong><%= f.label :gender%></strong><br>
```

Comment: Please add all your code so we can help you

Comment: Apparently, your `Article` model doesn't have a `phone` field.

Comment: Have you added `:phone` column in the `articles`  table?
If **no** please add. If **yes** you must have forgot to run the migration

Answer (score 0):

Your answer is @Stefan comment from the comment section

**How to add this?**

On the `articles` table not exists the `phone` column, you can add this using `migration` like

```
rails g migration AddPhoneToArticles phone:integer
```

Here `phone:string` `phone` is column name and `integer` is its data type you can change the data type which you need like `string`

then run the migration like

```
rails db:migrate #only available in Rails 5.x version
#or
rake db:migrate
```

Look at the [`Creating a Migration`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#creating-a-migration) in Rails official guide

Comment: `rails db:migrate` is rails 5 specific command. It  will raise `Error: Command 'db:migrate' not recognized` for rails 4 and below

Comment: Good point, but for beginners now I think it automatically create rails project based on rails 5, ok updating this point @DeepakMahakale